# How to set a divs height by editing the css with query?

Tags: jquery, css, height

Pretty new to jquery so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm trying to set a divs height (#banner_space) to  the height of an image with the class #banner_img. Like I said I'm really new to this, and this may be a really dumb question so please don't judge. Just trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var imgHeight = $('#banner_img').height();
        $("#banner_space").height(imgHeight);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `an image with the class #banner_img`. Either you meant ID, or you meant class, in which case it would be `$('.banner_img')`, as `.`'s select classes.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah theyre both IDs, my mistake!

Comment: So what is your question? Does the code work?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the css of elements in two ways:

single style

```
$('#banner_space').css('height',$('#banner_img').height());
```

multi-style

```
$('#banner_space').css({
    height : $('#banner_img').height(),
    width : '300px',
    border : '1px solid #afa'
});
```

Here is an example of using the css call http://jsfiddle.net/dYzpe/

Of course you can store the image height in a variable as in your example,.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgHeight = $('#banner_img').height();
    $('#banner_space').css('height',imgHeight);
    $('#banner_space').css({
        height : imgHeight
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the closing parentheses before ending </script> tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var imgHeight = $('#banner_img').height();
     $("#banner_space").height(imgHeight);
 });
</script>
```